# Can content be recovered in this situation?

Tags: wp-admin

I'm just a front end designer working on a website for a client. Yesterday, the client attempted to update the theme. However, it crashed during installation (most likely due to a host server fault) and resulted in the white screen syndrome.

Unfortunately the client didn't have a recent back up. The hosting provider managed to restore a version from a few days ago. They say they've moved the broken version to separate server because the latest content is still there.

Now here's the crux: The restored website has doesn't have all the work I did on Tuesday. I would like to avoid having to do all that work again.

So my question is: Can the content (Parent/Child theme) that's been put aside be extracted and added to the current version of the site? And if so, what would be the strategy? What kind of expert would the client need to enlist? What complications would there be?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as my schedule is tight and I would really like to avoid having to do all that work again.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by content? Page and post content, or theme files?

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for the comment. I assume page and post content (if that includes the design elements rows, modules, css)? Please forgive my ignorance - am still learning.

Comment: If the old content is still accessible, you need a WordPress expert to look a this old content and he will find what can be recover.

Comment: @simon33  There are quite a few "if"s here.  we don't know the theme you're using or how it's setup.  Depending on what "changes" you did (css, php, content from backend) you may be able to recover.  The short answer is "yes" you can recover parts of a theme.  provide some examples of what you "changed" though.  ie edited css, or header.php?

Comment: Rudtek, thank you for taking the time to respond. However, it's no longer an issue. All the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to guess what kind of a "crash" happened and why did it require the drastic roll back of the site.

As far as themes go — they are normally just folders of code (if not going into complicated ones with page builders and such).

- If that code survived somewhere in your case — it can be easily moved to a different (version) of the site.
- If it was erased — the time and costs for attempting to restore it would likely exceed what is reasonable.

As opposed to theme, the *content* lives entirely in database, not filesystem. Again — it's either survived in some form or it didn’t, depending on what went down.

In a nutshell — enumerate the work you did, inquire if it's still preserved in some form.

PS Usual lessons — use version control and such. :)

Comment: Thank you, Rarst. Yes, lesson learnt all round. It was the client that spoke to the host. So I'm not sure on the exact details. I can get them if necessary. And yes, apparently the code did survive. It's just been moved elsewhere.

Comment: Just re-read your comment and picked up on a relevant point. It was a theme with a native page builder.

Comment: If your work consisted of working with page builder _that_ might be a lot more involved to restore out of non-functioning site. The biggest problem would probably be that it would require a very competent knowledge of _how and what_ specific page builders stores, which is much more involved than merely _using_ one.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to share your thoughts, Rarst. So we would need someone with expert knowledge of the particular page builder?

Comment: Yep, that sounds right from your description of the situation.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this. Enjoy the rest of your day.

Comment: There's a very good chance it would take much more time and effort to attempt to restore your work than it would to redo it. I'm sure that's frustrating, but it's probably not worth seeking and paying an expert. Since the client was the one who made the change that broke the site, I'd say it's fair to bill the client for the additional hours. Unless you are working on a contract that doesn't cover you for this scenario, in which case, also learn the lesson that contracts need a clause for covering time spent that's unrecoverable.

Comment: You guys are awesome. I appreciate your logic. Elaine, that's exactly how it panned out. Right now I'm with a pot of coffee working into the night, playing catch up. Cheers everyone.